# Query not detecting input further out then column AH

Tags: google-sheets, match, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

So, I have a quite large pool of data, which I am query'ing thru a drop-down menu.

However, whenever I put the query to look for a column further out the `AH`, I get no results at all.

I have made sure all cells are set to "`Plain text`"

This one is working, up to `AH`, if I put it at `AI` or further, **I get an empty result**.

```
=Query({J5:CE500},"Select Col"&match(E3,J3:AH3)&",Col"&match(E3,J3:AH3)+1&",Col"&match(E3,J3:AH3)+2&",Col"&match(E3,J3:AH3)+3)
```

There are no real errors, just text not showing in `column 2-5`, as would be expected

Link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LQK6chD_nLS1JX_jXt8pNGeCwKUTvYT2Lo_0CI0Pk2A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Since the column labels are calculated, please add the values of the referred cells. By the way usually Google Sheets questions that also include a link to a demo spreadsheet are well received and get answers sooner.

Comment: Here is a link to the spreadsheet.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LQK6chD_nLS1JX_jXt8pNGeCwKUTvYT2Lo_0CI0Pk2A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: query is not so good with super large ranges

Answer (score 0):

replace your formula with this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(3, MATCH(E2, G2:2, 0)+6, 4)&":"&
 ADDRESS(200, MATCH(E2, G2:2, 0)+9, 4)))
```

[image: 0]